# Is there any way I can use PhoenixAnalysis Engine with FxCop 10?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, fxcop

In my company we are using VS 2010 Professional edition, which doesn't support Source code analysis in built. So I am using FxCop 10 to resolve this issue. Our client side developer team is using VS 2010 ultimate, in which SCA is inbuilt and few of the SCA warning treated as errors in some projects. Now I am getting some warnings from FxCop like this

```
Warning: Unrecognized rule 'Microsoft.Globalization/CA1303:Do not pass literals as localized parameters'. 
Warning: Unrecognized rule'Microsoft.Globalization/CA1303'.
```

I don't know how to enable FxCop to recognize these warnings.

After searching I found it is [implemented by new kind of rule engine PhoenixAnalysis, it was not shipping with FxCop standalone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/04/14/data-flow-analysis-rules-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx), I found it in the Visual Studio 2010 FxCop folder. I copied the PhoenixAnalysis.dll to FxCop 10 engines folder, but it is not working. 
Is there any workaround, I can use PhoenixAnalysis or recognize globalization warnings?

Answer (score 0):

The Phoenix engine and dataflow rules are only licensed with VS 2010 Premium and Ultimate, so such a workaround would presumably violate your license agreement.

If your intent is simply to avoid the warnings due to SuppressMessageAttribute instances that refer to rules that FxCop does not recognize, you might want to consider using the same workaround used by some StyleCop users: create a dummy FxCop rule assembly that includes empty rules that match the signature of the missing rules.

Comment: No I don't want to avoid warnings, I want to verify those rules.

Comment: I am unaware of any way to license the Phoenix engine and dataflow rules without purchasing VS 2010 Premium or Ultimate.